# How to retrieve the current Windows NLA network location from command-line?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, scripting, command-line-interface

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain controller which *always* sets its NLA location to 'Network 3' after a reboot.  Without fail, this defaults to Public, which screws with my Domain profile firewall settings.  I have to manually disable and re-enable the network adapter before it will set itself back to the domain profile.

I've tried [KB2524478](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2524478/en-us) and a whole host of other things.  Now I'm tired of trying to fix this problem (and fast running out of time) so just want to get around it.  I was thinking about scripting the disable/enable with `netsh` and being done with it, but I'd like to go one step further and make sure that the NLA location *is* actually "Network 3" and not "the-domain.example.org" (more specifically, just checking it is not the domain) before I do.  That way, I can schedule it more frequently than just on startup.

I'm just missing a piece of this puzzle — how to retrieve the location using something I can pipe to `FIND /i "the-domain.example.org"`, so I can run it as:

```
<something> | ...
FIND /i "the-domain.example.org" || ...
NETSH interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=DISABLED & ...
NETSH interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=ENABLED
```

So what is `<something>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query the appropriate registry keys to see what the network profile is set to. You need to look in `\HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures` to find the subkey for the appropriate interface. This will require a little detective work but the easiest way is look for the MAC address of your *current* default gateway. Once you've located the interface's SubKey take note of the ProfileGUID. You can then use the ProfileGUID to locate that interface's Profile settings `..\NetworkList\Profiles`. From there setting the REG_DWORD:Category back to 2 should set the interface's profile to Domain.

You need to turn off the NLA service before you make the change to the Category attribute. A simple `net stop nlasvc` will stop NLA and netprofm. Once you make the registry change restart it: `net start netprofm`.

Comment: Not bad. +1 for `netsh advfirewall set domainprofile state on`, at least, which might well be better than disable/re-enable.  I almost accepted it, but will go away and test that it enables the domain policy properly, first.  FWIW, I did eventually find the slightly alternate `netsh advfirewall monitor show currentprofile`, which gives me the domain name -- I will also check if it gives the names of non-domain network locations too (as that would *strictly* answer the question I asked).  In any case, if your approach works I will use it for the actual fix, as it seems cleaner than mine, IMO.

Comment: You will want to play around with the firewall profile settings and make sure you're actually getting *just* the Domain Profile with `netsh advfirewall set domainprofile state on`. I added the `allprofiles state off` just to be sure in my edit.

Comment: Still testing, but I think `netsh advfirewall set domainprofile state on` just tells the server that, when in a Domain Profile, the Firewall should be on; I don't *think* it actually changes the current profile to Domain...

Comment: Just looked back over my notes. You are correct. Try the registry method.

Comment: OK, stuck with the disable/enable as it worked in my environment.  Used `netsh advfirewall show currentprofile | find /i "Domain" || netsh interface set interface name="LAN" admin=DISABLED & netsh interface set interface name="LAN" admin=ENABLED` as my command, which you put me on to with your (subsequently edited) first answer.  `netsh advfirewall monitor show currentprofile` does *technically* give the name of the current location, if anyone else is looking for that specific need...